# Computed Property is defined in Vue Devtools, but not accessible by 'this' in mounted() hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I use a computed property to return the route params of the current user view. The returned value is defined in devtools, as you can see below, but when I try to access it in my `mounted()` function via a console.log, it returns as undefined. I was thinking that wrapping the console.log in a `$nextTick` would resolve this, but it doesn't. I'm out of ideas.

DevTools Screenshot:

[image]

My code:

```
  updated() {
    this.fetchGroupMessages();
  },
  mounted() {
    let listenerID = "UNIQUE_LISTENER_ID";
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.getUser();
      console.log(this.reservationId);
    });
  },
computed: {
    reservationId() {
      return this.$route.params.reservationId;
    }
  },
```

For more context, I'm building a chat app that gets initialized in `App.vue` in its `beforeCreated()` hook, and then the user is authenticated in the `created()` hook. Finally, the `Chat.vue` component renders if `isLoggedIn == true`.

EDIT: The route/URL

```
export default {
    routes: [{
        path: "/admin",
        name: 'adminDashboard',
        component: AdminDashboard
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "dashboard",
        component: Dashboard
    },
    {
        name: "bookings",
        path: "/bookings",
        component: Bookings
    },
    {
        path: "/reservation/:reservationId",
        children: [
            { path: "", component: Gallery },
            { path: "media/:mediaId", component: Media }
        ],
        component: Reservation
    },
    {
        name: "shopping-cart",
        path: "/bag",
        component: ShoppingCart
    },
    {
        name: "Thanks",
        path: "/thanks",
        component: Thanks
    }],
    add: function (component) {
        this.routes.push({
            path: component.path,
            children: component.children,
            name: component.name,
            component: component
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you put console logging inside the `reservationId` function? That would be both to check the value and to check the timing relative to the `mounted` hook. Also, are you transitioning between routes or are you always on the same one?

Comment: What happen when you log this.$route.params to console from mounted() ?

Comment: @skirtle When I console log 'hello!' inside the reservationId function, it shows up. But not if I console log the $route.params. It will just show up as {}. Also, I'm always on the same route.

Comment: @farincz I get undefined.

Comment: The picture you posted showed `reservationId` with a value. Do you not see the console logging inside `reservationId` called again to populate that value? It might help if you could post the route config and the URL.

Comment: @skirtle Nope, the console-logging is not called again. That's what's so weird. I edited my question to include the route config and path.

Comment: Oh, I should mention that reservationId is defined if I console.log in an updated() hook instead of mounted() and trigger some sort of data change.

Comment: I see the route config but you haven't posted the URL, so I don't know what route you're hitting. Could you also confirm which component contains the `mounted` hook included in the question and (if it isn't obvious) how that is related to the components in the route config. Regarding the logging, the value seen in the dev tools (or in the `updated` hook) must be coming from somewhere. If you aren't seeing it logged from within the computed function it isn't just weird, it is indicative that you're misinterpreting something, like caching or a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass `router` into the `Vue` configuration.  That's what makes `$route` reactive.